# Deleting Orchard CMS HtmlWidget in code

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a HtmlWidget with an IdentityPart with an Id value like "/Identifier=40b3f227-61af-4d8b-95c9-53bd6021a70e".

```
  <HtmlWidget Id="/Identifier=40b3f227-61af-4d8b-95c9-53bd6021a70e" Status="Published">
    <IdentityPart Identifier="40b3f227-61af-4d8b-95c9-53bd6021a70e" />
    ....
```

What would be the right way to delete a widget like this in code?
I assume we grab the object using the contentmanager somehow and delete or unpublish it.  But I am not sure about the exact mechanics of doing that.  Would appreciate an example and some guidance on the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you retrieve the item the item using the content manager as you have suggested. For example if you wanted to retrieve the item by its identity:

```
var item = _contentManager.Query<IdentityPart, IdentityPartRecord>()
    .Where(c => c.Identifier == "40b3f227-61af-4d8b-95c9-53bd6021a70e")
    .Slice(0, 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you pass the retrieved content item back to the content manager to remove or unpublish:

```
if (item != null)
{
    //delete the item - remains in the db but is no longer a draft or published
    _contentManager.Remove(item.ContentItem);
    //or unpublish
    _contentManager.Unpublish(item.ContentItem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, damoclarke.  That's exactly what I needed to see!

Comment: The Identifier field is an ntext field that cannot be used in a predicate but your answer gave me the pattern I was looking for.